# Need to convert a class into another class with distinct value collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class

```
 public class SwiftCodeInfo
    {
      public string Country {get; set;}
      public string SwiftCode {get; set;}
      public string BranchCode {get; set;}
    }
```

and this class has value

```
var swiftCodeInfo = new List<SwiftCodeInfo>();

swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="USA", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCode="101"});
swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="USA", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCode="102"});
swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="USA", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCode="103"});
swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="USA", SwiftCode ="XYZABCDEF", BranchCode="104"});
swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="USA", SwiftCode ="XYZABCDEF", BranchCode="105"});
swiftCodeInfo.Add(new SwiftCodeInfo{Country ="IND", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCode="106"});
```

Now there is another class

```
 public class BranchCode
        {
          public string Country {get; set;}
          public string SwiftCode {get; set;}
          public List<string> BranchCodes {get; set;}
        }
```

And I want values in class BranchCodes like this

```
var Branches = new List<BranchCode>{
           new BranchCode{Country = "USA", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCodes = new List<string>{"101","102","103"}},
           new BranchCode{Country = "USA", SwiftCode ="XYZABCDEF", BranchCodes = new List<string>{"104","105"}},
           new BranchCode{Country = "IND", SwiftCode ="ABCDEFGH", BranchCodes = new List<string>{"106"}}   
    };
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `GroupBy` the `Country`, `SwiftCode`

```
swiftCodeInfo.GroupBy(l => new { l.Country, l.SwiftCode })
             .Select(g => new BranchCode {
                    Country = g.Key.Country, 
                    SwiftCode = g.Key.SwiftCode, 
                    BranchCodes = g.Select(i => i.BranchCode).ToList() 
                });
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G6DGxW)